# Going through a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How do I go trough a list in Haskell when the list looks like:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

and I want to take the first 3 elements:

```
[1,2,3]
```

and then go to the next 3 elements:

```
[2,3,4]
```

and so on...

Comment: fpcomplete's hoogle searches more widely than haskell.org's: searching for a function which takes a list and an integer and gives you a bunch of lists [a]->Int->[[a]] [has some handy results](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle?q=%5Ba%5D+-%3E+Int+-%3E+%5B%5Ba%5D%5D&env=ghc-7.8-stable-14.09)

Comment: Take them and do what with them? Go on in what context? The question is rather vague.

Comment: What should happen at the end of the list?

Comment: @dfeuer: I expect `[1,2,3],[2,3,4],…,[7,8,9],[8,9,10]`, aka `\xs -> zipWith3 (\a b c -> [a,b,c]) xs (drop 1 xs) (drop 2 xs)`. But I'm not OP.

Comment: You don't "go" through a list. Or any other data structure. What's that even supposed to mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `zipWith3`:

```
zipWith3 (\a b c -> [a,b,c]) xs (drop 1 xs) (drop 2 xs)
```

But why stop there when one can generalize?

```
subLists :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
subLists n xs = 
   let ts = take n xs
   in if length ts == n 
         then ts : subLists n (tail xs)
         else []
```

This solution could be improved by `takeN :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe [a]`, so that one doesn't need to check the length of `ts`, but that's left as an exercise ;).

Answer (score 3):

Define your function like this `slideThree (x:y:z:xs) =`  and in your recursive call, call it like this `slideThree (y:z:xs)`

Make sure to add the proper checks if the list contains at least three elements.

Comment: You mean `slideThree (y:z:xs)`, perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

To create a sliding list of elements we can use [`tails`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:tails) from Data.List

```
slide :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
slide n xs =
  (filter (\xs -> length xs == n) . -- filter out all of length n
   map (take n) . -- take only the first n elements of every tail
   tails) xs -- find all tails
```

Using it:

```
λ> slide 3 [1..12]
[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6],[5,6,7],[6,7,8],[7,8,9],[8,9,10],[9,10,11],[10,11,12]]
λ> map (\(x:y:z:[]) -> x + y + z) it
[6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33]
```

Comment: I like the `tails` usage, but `filter` and `length` bother me. At the first glance, `takeWhile` would be better. Then, what if to calculate the length manually? That could, however, force the list and probably break fusion.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are good - I just want to add that there's a succinct list comprehension:

```
[[x,y,z] | x:y:z:_ <- tails xs]
```

Obviously this wouldn't work so well if you wanted 1000-element sublists rather than 3.

Also, you should probably ignore this but I can't resist throwing in a fun point-free answer:

```
zipWith (const (take 3)) <$> drop 2 <*> tails
```